# Height of uniform distribution?

Tags: probability, uniform-distribution

If X follows a uniform distribution in the interval [2, 7], what is the height of the probability density function (pdf) at x = 4?

I'm new to Probability & Statistics and will appreciate any help!

Comment: Have you tried to graph the PDF? What do you know about the uniform distribution?

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

- If it is a uniform distribution then the density is constant on the support of the random variable.
- If the density is $f(x)$ on the support between $a$ and $b$, you want $\displaystyle \int_a^b f(x) \, dx = 1$ as this is a probability
- So you want to find $h$ where $\displaystyle \int_2^7 h \, dx = 1$. Or you could sketch a rectangle